# How can I configure ASP.NET Core routing to route to controllers (without optional action) if they exist, then fall back to a default route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller which serves up 'static pages' with a `key` column which allows for a URL to be entered. For example, `http://hostname/about` should route to a controller called `StaticPages` and any other URL which does not link to a controller (with or without action).

The intention is for the routing to work in the following order:

1. Area routes
2. Controller routes (with/without action)
3. Default route - static page lookup through `StaticPages` controller

I have the following routing configured, however I am unable to achieve the above configuration.

If I navigate to a static page (i.e. `/about`) this works, however if I navigate to a controller without an action specified (i.e. `/blog`), I get a 404 which suggests its skipping to the bottom route pattern. If I use a controller and action (i.e. `/blog/index`) this works correctly, so it appears to be expecting an action, which I'd rather be set as `index` by default.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                "admin-area",
                "admin",
                "admin/{controller}/{action}/{Id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "admin-users",
                pattern: "admin/users/{action=Index}/{Id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "UserAdmin", action = "Index" });
           
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "StaticPage-Default",
               pattern: "{key}",
               defaults: new { controller = "StaticPages", action = "Details" });


            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

How can I acheive the described configuration?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with just a routing table. Based on your description and routing table, `/about` and `/blog` both match `default` and `StaticPage-Default` routes, with the latter being a better fit. I don't see a way around this with routing alone - perhaps some additional work/redirects in the `StaticPage` controller, which effectively becomes your catch-all. Alternatively, if there are just a few controllers such as `/blog`, you can list them explicitly: `pattern: "/blog/{action=Index}/{id?}"`, or use `[Route]` attribute on each controller. I don't see a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly, converting the admin parts at the top to an area (properly - I hadn't configured this correctly) and replacing the code with the following allowed me to acheive the desired behaviour, although I'm not entirely sure I understand why.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "admin-area",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "StaticPage-Default",
               pattern: "{key}",
               defaults: new { controller = "StaticPages", action = "Details" });

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```